# Checking which element is bigger when merging two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have two arrays that are the same length, for example `var a = [5,2,6,2,7,5];` and `var b = [2,3,7,4,3];`.
I also have another array which is `var c = [0,0,0,0,0];`

How do I compare `a` and `b` to put the highest element into `c` which in this case should become `[5,3,7,7,5];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Your two arrays of the same length are not of the same length.

Answer (score 2):

ES6 single-line solution:

```
c = a.map((a, i) => a > b[i] ? a : b[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

Array#map into a new array, and take the max of the current number from `a`, and the number with the same index from array `b`:

```js
const a = [5, 2, 6, 2, 7];
const b = [2, 3, 7, 4, 3];
const c = a.map((num, i) => Math.max(num, b[i]));

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would iterate through both arrays, doing the comparison at each step, and inserting the larger number:

*Note*: Even though you mention that you have equal length arrays, the two sample arrays you've given don't have the same length so my example uses similar equal-length arrays:

```js
let a = [5, 2, 6, 2, 7]
let b = [2, 3, 7, 4, 3]
let c = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

// we can use a single loop index `i` since the arrays have same length
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

  // take the current number from a and from b
  let numA = a[i]
  let numB = b[i]

  // determine larger of the two numbers
  let largerNumber = numA > numB ? numA : numB

  // add larger to array at current position
  c[i] = largerNumber
}

console.log(c)
```

You can simplify your solution to be a simple map operation, as [demonstrated by dhilt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46869514/3928341).

Comment: He stated c already initialized. so instead of c.push(largerNumber), "c[i] = largerNumber;"

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple `for` loop:

```js
var a = [2, 3, 7, 8];
var b = [3, 2, 5, 9];
var c = [0, 0, 0, 0];

for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
  c[i] = a[i] > b[i] ? a[i] : b[i];
}

console.log("Result: "+c);
```

Comment: missing indexes []

Comment: Your c in the for loop block should be c[i] = a[i] > b[i] ? a[i] : b[i]

Answer (score -1):

see example:

```js
var a = [5,2,6,2,7,5];
var b = [2,3,7,4,3];
var c = [0,0,0,0,0];
for(var i in c){
 c[i]=a[i]>b[i]?a[i]:b[i];
}
console.log('result:' + c);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this, below code takes two arrays and gives the result of max number

```
var array=[5,3,7,7,5];
var array2 = [5,6,4];
var array3=array.concat(array2);
var max=array3.sort((a,b)=>b-a)[0];
console.log("Result: " + max);
```